# Push notifications with image and URL using firebase not working

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notifications with image and URL using firebase. When I'm sending using firebase dashboard it is not working. I have two questions is there any way to send notification with image using firebase dashboard. If not possible can I read FCM registration tokens that are saved in firebase database?

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]
I'm trying to send custom data to send rich push notifications and following is my push IOS response:

```
APPDELEGATE: willPresentNotification {
aps =     {
    alert = "Testing with Rich Notifications";
    sound = default;
};
"gcm.message_id" = "0:1502789329372721%69bfae7a69bfae7a";
"gcm.n.e" = 1;
"gcm.notification.sound2" = default;
"google.c.a.c_id" = 1621049923337072908;
"google.c.a.e" = 1;
"google.c.a.ts" = 1502789328;
"google.c.a.udt" = 0;
mediaType = png;
mediaUrl = "https://mazadat.ae//themes/electric/assets/images/notification_logo.png";
"mutable_content" = true;
}
```

According to apple requirements for rich push notifications mutable_content parameter should be in aps dictionary.

Comment: Hi. Did you found any solution for the same?

Comment: Hi, Did found any solution?